# Tension in a string attached to different masses

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram, string

Does tension in a string remain same even if masses attached to it are of different weights?

I have provided a diagram, according to me the tension in string should be different as masses hanging are different. My teacher has told me that tension in string will remain same.

Please explain why does it remain same?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if we consider pullies ideal,frictionless and string massless then the tension in a string will be equal throught the string if the mass attached to it is stationary. However ideal strings and frictionless pullies don't exist in real life.

If mass are moving and pullies have friction then pullies should start rotating because of torque produced by inbalanced forces. and here inbalanced forces are differnt tension in string

If strings have mass then the tension in the string varies point to point as mass of the string also causes in increase in tension down the string

In above diagram the pully attached to M is fixed and can't move but pully attached to m' can move vertically

We have
M moving downwards,

(M)g - T1 = M(a1)

m' moving upwards
Assume T3 be tension in string connecting m' and first pully

T3 - (m') g = (m')a2

Answer (score 0):

Assuming frictionless pullies, and massless string, the tension at all 3 points marked on the string will always be equal to each other. With heavier masses the tension may be higher, but it will be higher at all 3 points, so the tension, higher or lower, will always be equal at all 3 points.

Answer (score 0):

Your concern is very genuine ! See whenever we work with mechanics of pulleys and ropes at undergraduate level we try to make some assumptions these include :- $ 1) $ massless pulley $2)$ frictionless string  $3)$ inextensible string  . These are the only tools needed to answer the question you raise ;-) so let's begin in why the tension is taken to be same in the connecting string. For this let's assume we just don't know anything so here is the first diagram that comes to our mind :- [image] from the figure first deduce that as linear acceleration of fixed pulley is zero it has tension equal in both the arms. Then for the fixed pulley consider the torque $\tau$ about it's centre then $\tau=I\alpha$ but $ I = 0 $ hence $\tau=0$ which implies that $ T_{3}=T_{2} $ here we use assumption $ 2 $ primarily

Answer (score 0):

An ideal string is assumed to be massless
Lets consider an elementary part of the string having mass $dm$ and acceleration a
Writing equation of dynamics for elementary part we have
$T1-T2=dma$
But $dm=0$ (assumption)
Therefore $T1=T2$
And this result is independent of masses attached